# Stop at 1 level while traversing account hierarchy using parent accounts

Tags: account, hierarchy

I have an interesting requirement. The requirement is that if an account is a parent account and a custom field is changed say account manager field, then immediately update the children of the parent accounts with only one level. In other words, i should update the immediate children underneath them but i should never update the sub children of the children even though they might be parent accounts.

Now here is the account. My trigger fires on an account insert or update and it queries the children and updates the account manager field in them. But since child accounts are updated, it fires the trigger again and it updates the sub children which i dont want. How do i make sure that i can just fire the trigger for only the account created or edited in context? 
Since there was no session id, is there a variable which i can keep as static within the execution context and refer it so that it can only fire once?
Thanks
Buyan

Comment: static variables will be retained for the life of the transaction so simply keep a list of ids that you will be updating in a set; then, when trigger recurses, before applying your child creation logic again, check the set for the current record's ID. If found, skip

Comment: Hi Ratan, thanks for your answer. I am doing this using flow and process builder. Do you know how to create a static variable in flow or process builder?

Comment: Buyan -- Please [Edit] your [post then to indicate you are using Flows and not Triggers as this may be confusing. Or are you using Flows/Process Builder to do a field update and that executes your triggers?  Regardless, please clarify by using [Edit]